# More flexible objective definitions with the nloptr package

Tags: r

I'm using the `nloptr` package and everything works well. But I need a way to define the objective function and the constraints in a faster way. I can't write all the settings by hand each time.

For example, I want to solve this problem:

```
library(nloptr)

eval_f <- function(x){
  return(x[4]^2+x[7]^2+x[9]^2)
}
x0 = c(1,1,1,1,0.5,0,0.5,1,0)

hin <- function(x){
  h <- numeric(6)
  h[1] = x[1]+x[4]-x[2]-x[5]-0.01
  h[2] = x[1]+x[4]-x[3]-x[6]-0.01
  h[3] = x[2]+x[5]-x[3]-x[6]-0.01
  h[4] = x[2]+x[8]-x[1]-x[7]-0.01
  h[5] = x[2]+x[8]-x[3]-x[9]-0.01
  h[6] = x[1]+x[7]-x[3]-x[9]-0.01
  return(h)
}

heq <- function(x){
  h <- numeric(1)
  h[1] <- x[1]+x[2]+x[3]-3
  return(h)
}


res <- slsqp(x0=x0,fn=eval_f,hin = hin,heq = heq)
```

Everything works.
But I want to define the objective function in a faster way.  Can I pass another argument (the indices) to the function in an automatic way? For example:

```
eval_f <- function(x,indices){
      return(x[indices]^2)
    }
```

I tried but I have an error.

Comment: maybe you want `sum(x[indices]^2)`?  We could really use a **reproducible** example ([mcve]): at least tell us what error message you got!

Comment: this is an example. I need to solve a bigger problem.
However, yes I want something like sum(x[indices]^2)
But the slsqp function give me the error, because variable "indices" is not defined. I don't know, how to passo to the slsqp external parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `...` argument to `slsqp` allows you to pass arbitrary arguments through to the objective function. So define a new objective function that takes `indices` as an argument:

```
eval_f2 <- function(x,indices){
  return(sum(x[indices]^2))
}
```

... and include `indices=c(4,7,9)` (to match your previous objective function's definition):

```
res2 <- slsqp(x0=x0,fn=eval_f2, hin = hin,heq = heq, indices=c(4,7,9))
```

Check the solution:

```
all.equal(res$par,res2$par) ## TRUE
```

### factories

More generally, you can define a *factory* - a function that returns a function.  This works because functions have associated *environments* in which variables (such as the indices) can be stored. This will work even in cases where the top-level function doesn't allow arbitrary arguments to be passed through (and may e.g. be important if you want to use *different* sets of indices for your objective and constraint functions ...)

```
eval_factory <- function(indices) {
    fun <- function(x) {
        return(sum(x[indices]^2))
    }
    return(fun)
}

res3 <- slsqp(x0=x0, fn=eval_factory(indices=c(4,7,9)),
              hin = hin,heq = heq)
all.equal(res$par,res3$par) ## TRUE
```

#### factory for hin

```
hin_factory <- function(A,b) {
    fun <- function(x) {
        return((A %*% x) + b)
    }
    return(fun)
}

A0 <- matrix(c(1, -1,  0, 1,-1,  0, 0, 0, 0,
               1,  0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0,
               0,  1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0,
              -1,  1,  0, 0, 0,  0,-1, 1, 0,
               0,  1, -1, 0, 0,  0, 0, 1, -1,
               1,  0, -1, 0, 0,  0, 1, 0, -1),
             byrow=TRUE,ncol=9)

all.equal(c(hin_factory(A0,-0.01)(x0)),hin(x0))

res4 <- slsqp(x0=x0, fn=eval_factory(indices=c(4,7,9)),
              hin = hin_factory(A0,b=-0.01), heq = heq)

all.equal(res$par, res4$par)
```